# How do you describe, in English, a set of different ethnic groups in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am from Holland. In Dutch, we have the word "Volk" to describe the masses of people formed by a group with genetic, cultural, and ideological bonds and similarities. So in Dutch "Volk" is the proper original noun for "ethnic group" just as in English the proper original noun is "folk" (and not "people", since "people" is latinate).

Now in Holland we use the words "Volken" or "Volkeren" to describe the plural of the word "Volk", so they describe a set of several different ethnic groups. We use the word "Volks" when we use it as an adjective, both in the singular and plural forms. As a singular term, it would translate into English as "folkish".

However I am searching for the translation of the adjective used as a plural. In English, a plural is mostly created with an "s" after the singular, so that would make "folks". However, where "folks" in English can be used to define just a group of people, "Volken" or "Volkeren" as nouns in Dutch would never mean just a group of people, just as the Dutch adjective "Volks" used in the plural never would. It would always mean a set of different ethnic groups.

So now I am searching for one single word that, as in Dutch, describes "a set of different ethnic groups" like the word "Volks" without running the risk that folks think I am just talking about "a set of people". There is a large difference between the definitions of "a set of different ethnic groups" and "a set of people", and I need to make a headline in which I have only room for one word to communicate the correct meaning.

I should be able to use it in the translation of the Dutch sentence

> "En het vrije volks verbond leeft voort...."

which in English would be

> "And the free XXXX federation lives on...."

where XXXX is the word I am searching for.

Comment: I think the nearest "equivalent" word in English would be "race" (n), and "racial"(adj). But the problem is that the word has become so loaded that most people would hesitate to use it for everyday purposes, hence the adoption of rather coy expressions such as "ethnic group", "community" etc. Certainly *folk* used to exist in the sense of *volk* in Saxon English, and we have counties named e.g. *Norfolk* (north folk), and *Suffolk* (south folk). Presumably Dutch has an equivalent of the German *rasse*. How does its use correspond to *volk*?

Comment: OED sense !a. (confirmed obsolete) A people, nation, race, tribe. Ælfric Genesis xxv. 23   Twa folc beoþ todæled on þe, & þæt folc oferswið þæt oþer folc.
1297   R. Gloucester's Chron. (1724) 3   Brytones were þe firste folc þat to Engelond come.
1388   Bible (Wycliffite, L.V.) John xi. 48   Romayns schulen come, and schulen take our place and oure folk.
1535   Bible (Coverdale) 2 Esdras v. 26   Amonge all ye multitudes of folkes thou hast gotten the one people.
1851   J. M. Neale Mediæval Hymns 23   Met Thee with Palms in their hands that day the folk of the Hebrews.

Comment: You need to better explain why you don't like **peoples** with it's possessive **peoples'**, which is the word that native English speakers would use to complete your sentence. Latin origin? Sorry, that's English for you.

Comment: Back when they first came to prominence, [***the Beaker Folk***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Beaker+People%2CBeaker+Folk&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CBeaker%20People%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBeaker%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeaker%20People%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeaker%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CBeaker%20Folk%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBeaker%20Folk%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeaker%20folk%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeaker%20folk%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBEAKER%20FOLK%3B%2Cc0) were almost always called just that. But now they're often called ***the Beaker People***.

Comment: I think the answer would depend a bit on whether you are speaking of people in present times, or if you are speaking about some historic situation (see the Beaker Folk mentioned above). So what is the subject of what you are writing?

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is a very interesting question. Clearly *folk* in the sense described has been lost from English, but retained in languages like German and Dutch. It is odd because there is no obvious Latinized replacement. Indeed from OED examples it appears to have fallen out of use in the sixteenth century. There are examples of it from both Wycliffe's and Coverdale's bibles, but none quoted from the KJV.

Comment: You state that _volk_ translates to “ethnic group” (two words).  So why are you so insistent that _volken_ translate to only one word?

Comment: What's wrong with "culture/cultures"?

Comment: Or if Peoples is out, then ethnicities?

Comment: What's wrong with latin?

Comment: @Spencer - off the point a little - but the apostrophe in *peoples'* is good. That in *it's* is not good. That means *it is*. Here *its* is needed ! That's English...

Comment: @Tim Yes; sorry. Autocorrect on a phone plus a 5 - minute edit limit for comments.

Comment: @Sentinel if asker doesn't want a 'latination', then a 'greekery' is going to be right out...

Comment: "Folk" in English is completely non-specific. For example, I could talk about the "folk" wandering by my store, and that implies absolutely no relation whatsoever between them (other than that they all happened to be near my store that day for some reason).

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's 'that when they first came to prominence, the Beaker Folk were almost always called just that. But now they're often called the Beaker People', please? I first "met" them in about 1961-3 when they were very clearly "People" both in text books and on schools' radio…

Comment: I suggest a large part of what you see as a problem is trying to differentiate between "Folk" and "People" - which might be a “Latinisation” and is that what you said?

Broadly, English doesn’t; doesn’t even try to describe a set of different ethnic groups in one word. Why would it?

Please note that “why would it” is the whole and only point. There might be dozens of languages which make the distinction and Dutch might be one and most Germanic languages might do the same but English does not.

Comment: I know no Dutch but I notice "Volken" or "Volkeren" as plurals of "Volk" cannot work in English. Can you translate both words in a way that explains their difference, please?

Comment: @WGroleau Because there can be multiple translations for a given word or phrase, possibly? Translating "Volk" as "ethnic group" doesn't mean "the shortest possible valid translation for 'Volk' is 'ethnic group'", it means "'Volk' and 'ethnic group' mean the same thing". It's perfectly reasonable to then ask, "Is there a shorter way to say it?"

Comment: There would be a cultural or geographical label that regroups people of similar origin or culture, to define them specifically. i.e. Western, Christian, Catholic, polynesian, nordic, and the labels aren't precise, but are good for general debates.  after that you can use the word empire, peoples, cultures, groups, type cultures and so forth.

Comment: Fair enough, but he didn’t ask for a shorter way, he asked for a single word for the plural of something that he apparently thought two words was OK for.

Comment: @Robbie: As the NGram in my first comment clearly shows, ***Beaker Folk/People*** started to appear in the literature half a century before you encountered it in the early 60s. You can also see that over the 20-year period 1950-1970, the ***Folk*** version more than halved in popularity, to the point where by the *end* of those two decades, ***People*** actually became the more common version.  I was also at school in the early 60s, and my recollection is our textbooks used ***Folk***. Since I lived in a poor  area, perhaps our school used old textbooks that yours were throwing out! :)

Comment: Can the tile of this be changed to "single word meaning 'ethnic groups'"?

Comment: What is wrong with using citizens

Answer (score 71):

It's really, really difficult, sometimes impossible, to use  English without words that have a Latin origin. And really, ***peoples*** with its possessive ***peoples'***, is the first word a native English speaker would use. If a word came via Norman French, as "people" did, it's indubitably part of the English language.

In order to complete your example sentence, you  use the possessive of "peoples":

> ***And the free peoples' federation lives on....***

You could also use ***nations*** (such as in the Canadian term "First Nations") but that has an implication of political sovereignty and is just as derived from Latin. Possible candidate words in Old English could be ***slydeas*** or one of the derivatives of ***þéod*** such as ***ingeþeóde***, ***gumþéoda***, ***werþéoda*** (cf. Tolkien's name *Éothéod* for the Rohirrim), but if you used one of these, only a few people would know what you're talking about.

You may have found it difficult to find a definition for "peoples" in an online search, because of the way search engines work. Usually, it's buried in a definition for "people", such as the one at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people):

> **People** 5: (plural **peoples**) : a body of persons that are united by a common culture, tradition, or sense of kinship, that typically have common language, institutions, and beliefs, and that often constitute a politically organized group.

The definition [at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peoples) has a really good example, buried in a "usage note":

> *The aboriginal **peoples** of the Western Hemisphere speak many different languages.*

And of course we have no less a light than J.R.R. Tolkien, in *The Two Towers*, during Treebeard's perplexity over what kind of thing Merry and Pippin were:

> *Learn now the lore of the living creatures!*
>
> *First name the four, the free **peoples**,*
>
> *Eldest of all, the Elf-Children,*
>
> *Dwarf the delver, dark are his houses,*
>
> *Ent the earthborn, old as mountains,*
>
> *Man the mortal, master of horses...*

Tolkien clearly uses "peoples" to refer to several *different* but *distinct* groups of people.

**Update**: I was asked to address the concept of "peoples'  X of Y."  Google NGrams shows a huge ratio of "people's republic" to peoples' republic" and the first half dozen Google Books results for the latter were actually mistranscribed by Google -- they appear as "people's republic" in the actual books. My feel is that socialism is a homogenizing influence when it becomes the foundation of a state -- ideology is going to trump separate cultural identity.

Comment: I highly doubt there is any one English word that has ONLY the specific meaning the OP asks for and no others, but this is the closest.

Comment: Given that this is going to be the top answer for this question, you really should mention to OP that **"the People(s|') X of Y" is almost invariably a *Communist* state, not a descriptively multiethnic one**. If he's really aiming to describe many peoples working together without any suggestion of Marxism, he should just leave the word out of the name altogether and explain that it's a **Federation** or **Federative Republic**, which implicitly involves fairly powerful distinct regions working together.

Comment: @Ily:  The usage in English is exclusively (as far as I can tell) the ["People's Republic of Y"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Republic), not the "Peoples' Republic of Y".  But I agree that many people will make the association without paying close attention to the position of the apostrophe.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You're not wrong at all. ['People's Republic'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People's_Republic) has its own Wikipedia page and 'Peoples' Republic' isn't even a redirect but poke around on Google and you'll see that they'll just assume he misspelled the other, since that's what every use of it I can find amounts to. They've even got books whose titles talk about the 'Peoples' Republic of China'.

Comment: “The free peoples of the world” was if anything a slogan of Western leaders during the Cold War.  Winston Churchill said it in his 1946 “Iron Curtain” speech (and had been using it since at least 1938) and Harry Truman in his 1949 inaugural address. Although the phrase had been in use by other world leaders since at least 1910, It is likely that Tolkien consciously or unconsciously took the phrase from Churchill.

Answer (score 21):

You actually get quite close to the answer in your own question, where you say:

> Just as in English where the proper original noun is "Folk" (and not "People", since people is a latination).

Whatever you might like to call "the proper original noun", the commonly used word in English for "ethnic group" is "[People](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/people?s=t)":

> 4. the entire body of persons who constitute a community, tribe, nation, or other group by virtue of a common culture, history, religion, or the like: *the people of Australia; the Jewish people.*

<sup>*dictionary.com*</sup>

And, as that link says, the plural of people is **Peoples**. Anything belonging to them, or for them, would use the possessive apostrophe, making your sentence:

> "And the free **peoples'** federation lives on...."

Answer (score 18):

Disclaimer: I’m an American, and other people might use the same words differently.

You can say **ethnicities**, and one word for a society with many of them living together is **multiethnic**.

AndyT’s suggestion of **peoples** is good, and would be considered a literal translation of *volken*.  (Volkswagen is translated into English as “The People’s Car.”)  Winston Churchill spoke of “the free peoples of the world” at the start of the Second World War and the Cold War, and Harry Truman, in his 1948 inaugural address, also used this same phrase  It predates them; Teddy Roosevelt and Woodrow Wilson also said something similar.  More recently, former Secretary of State Hillary Rodham Clinton quoted Churchill’s version as well in her 2016 convention speech, and Vice-President Mike Pence talked about “the free peoples of the Americas” in a speech on August 15, 2017.

A place where many different ethnic groups live and mingle is **cosmopolitan**.  If they live in segregated neighborhoods and don’t mix very much, those are **ghettos** or various less-pejorative terms such as **enclaves**.  If they’re all assimilating to the same culture, it’s a **melting-pot**.  If they’re equal, not segregated, and don’t want to assimilate, that’s **multicultural**.  If each linguistic minority gets its own autonomous region, that might be called **cantons** after the districts of Switzerland, and a system like that is (with slightly negative connotation) **cantonized** or (more neutrally) **cantonal**.

Although I wouldn’t recommend it in this context, “peoples of the world” is a secondary meaning of the word **nations**, used for example in modern translations of the Bible.  Today, though, *nations* more often means countries, and using the word in the archaic sense might confuse people.  (Or, worse, give an American the impression you don’t think they’re a real American.)  It survives in the terms **nation-state** as distinct from a multiethnic state or a diaspora, and when we call an ethnic separatist trying to create a nation-state a **nationalist**.

**Cultures** comes close, but refers to customs and traditions, not to the people themselves; if a culture is dying out, that means that the people are still alive but their children are assimilating.

I would recommend against **races** in this context, although it wouldn’t offend anyone, because it has a slightly-different meaning.  Someone whose ancestors were from another continent might be fully-assimilated, especially in America, yet still considered a different race from the majority, and a proud nationalist who doesn’t speak the same language or dress the same might be considered the same race.  You’re not talking about their physical features.

The cognate **folk** exists in English, but has the wrong connotations (folk tales and folk wisdom connote rural superstitions).  The plural, **folks**, is best known for a cartoon character’s catchphrase, “That’s all, folks!” and is just slang for “You guys.”  Avoid the loanword *volk* in English.  It’s associated with Nazi Germany and has strong negative connotations.

Comment: This is an encyclopedic summary of these terms, which is great even if all of them don't fit OP's example sentence. Given it's thoroughness, however, you should go ahead and address the Communist association of countries named "the People's Foo of Freedonia".

Comment: @lly Add more paragraphs? Are you out of your volken mind? 

Comment: You could always just make the existing one longer and nix the aside about cantons, which are just going to make people think about dim sum and wontons anyway.

Comment: @lly True! :) Anyway, I know that Communists like to brand themselves as the People’s This of That, but they called their international organization the Communist International. There’s also a (very different) Socialist International. “The free peoples of the world” is a phrase commonly used by American presidents since the Cold War and not associated with Communists at all. Actually, I will go back and add in some examples.

Comment: Your remark about _races_ is not entirely correct. For those that know that, even scientifically, there is only one single human race, the perpetuation of the idea of multiple human races is in and of itself offensive (it is literally racist...).

Answer (score 4):

I would most likely use the word "community".
Very broad scope.

Answer (score 4):

In the Dutch expression:

> volks verbond

which is usually written as:

> volksverbond

the word "volks" is not a plural or an adjective, but the **genitive** of the singular noun "volk"; it comes from:

> des volks verbond

or, in less archaic Dutch:

> het verbond van het volk

So the correct translation is:

> people's federation

As the use of the singular "volk" indicates, it is a federation of members of one people or nation.

It should not be confused with "[volkenbond](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkenbond)" or "volkerenbond", the Dutch term for the "[League of Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations)". Here you have the plural "volken" and "volkeren" because the League of Nations is indeed a league of several nations or peoples.

Comment: Right, and the volk versus folk thing is a false friend.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, the question contains a lot of confusing information. I guess you have to understand Dutch to really make sense of it.

Comment: It annoys me when the kind of explanation you have given does not get the most support. It actually explains it in terms of the two languages. And here that is what is most relevant. A contrastive explanation and not one solely rooted in English.

Comment: @Lambie It's mostly a matter of timing; I only saw the question 24h after it had been posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "races" but that's pretty verboten these days; it has a raft of negative connotations attached to it. "Peoples" is also a grammatically appropriate term and probably better accepted by most readers.

Comment: "Peoples" with a capital "P", I would say.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco Yes I think you have a point there.

Comment: The most obvious explanation for the negative connotations may be the fact that there is only one human race,  for every definition of race except those that are based on negative intent.

Answer (score 1):

**Multicultural**

> relating to or constituting several cultural or ethnic groups within a society.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit the example sentence - by using an adjective, *"And the free multicultural federation lives on...."*, the word "free" now applies to the *federation*, not to the ethnic groups.

Comment: @TobySpeight The word 'free' will generally be understood as referring to the noun anyway, if it doesn't get a hyphen. This is the right answer if OP really wanted to emphasize the state's multiethnicity, even though no actual state has ever put it in their official name.

Comment: In the original, there was another (possessive) noun, which tends to attract the adjective more closely.  Compare "*free peoples' federation*" with  "*free multicultural federation*"; we don't hyphenate *_free-peoples'_, at least in part because we don't need to.  For a simpler example, an analogy is "*the red boats' flag*" (usually, the flag of the red boats) as compared to "*the red marine flag*" (the red flag of boats).

Answer (score 0):

There may be some problems with saying "races" but if you say "the races" that's not an insult -- it means multiple different ethnic groups, particularly multiple different ethnic *minority* groups.

Comment: _Race_ and _ethnic group_ are not synonyms. There are many ethnic groups, there is only one human race. The idea of there being multiple human races is not only outdated, it is scientifically incorrect.

Comment: Yes, but "the races" is a term that's used that way.  The popular song "I'll Take You There" contains the phrase "lying to the races".  (Yes, I know, it's anecdotal, so shoot me.)

Answer (score -3):

"Races" wouldn't work because it only suggests a genetic bond while ethnic groups also have cultural bonds.

"Nations" wouldn't work because it suggests a geographical boundary, while ethnic groups can live spread over several nations.

I thought "peoples" wouldn't work because "people" is often used in a more general sense without referring to a common ethnic background and "peoples" might suffer the same way.

But, if "peoples" used as an adjective ALWAYS refers to groups with different ethnic backgrounds, then I suppose that would be the way to go.

Pity, because the term "Free Folks Federation" has so much more creative possibilities than "Free Peoples Federation" and I just cannot come up with something that really sounds and alliterates equally well and communicates the same idea.

Comment: Sorry to break this to you, but ***every* paragraph of this is mistaken**. 'Races' can be understood as including cultural bonds but suffers from having been used by white pseudoscientists, imperialists, & racists. 'Nations' can be understood as referring to transnational ethnicities like the Germans & Italians, although that's a dated sense & needs some context to do so. Countable 'peoples' is an entirely different sense/word from uncountable 'people' but 'peoples' is a noun & never an adjective. Attributive nouns in English are nearly always singular. (A man 6 feet tall = a 6-foot-tall man.)

Comment: The 'Free Folks Federation' is alliterative in an *amusing* way, not a *euphonious* one. It's far *less* serious sounding than the 'Free Peoples' Federation' and provides *no* creative possibilities. The connotation is rural Southern English or 'old folks' homes' and not anything realistically political. That said, using 'the people' in your country's name at all doesn't make it sound folksy or inclusive; it makes it sound *Communist* because of the many many states which have used the term in their names.

Comment: Oh, there *is* that other association for 'folk' these days: [the freefolk who spoil *Game of Thrones*](http://www.reddit.com/r/freefolk) ON AN OPEN FIELD NED (and their namesakes in the books and show). If that *was* what you were going for, just go for it. And tell Cersei.

Comment: "folk" isn't really a serious word in English. It always sounds, well, *folksy*. I would avoid it in anything but the most casual of contexts.

Comment: Folk music, folk fashion, folk cuisine, folk art, folk traditions, folk dialectology -- all treated with great respect and taken very seriously where I'm from. That is not to say we don't enjoy those things, of course.

Comment: @Bread Yes, but those are adjectives. None of your examples are usages of the word "folk" to refer to actual people in the sense the OP is interested in.